# Safecracker Channel selection from radio selection

Tags: safecracker, forms

Is it possible to choose which channel a safecracker form should post to if you leave the safecracker's channel to ="" and then having a radio selection of the channel_id's??

is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with jQuery. The channels will all need to use the same field group.

When you add the [**channel parameter**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#channel) `channel=""` to your `exp:safecracker` tag, the tag renders that in the template as a hidden field with that channel's id number as the value. For example:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="7" />
```

You can change this value as needed with JS. I created a [**jsFiddle with working code**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPjyW/4/) that will get you started.

Comment: I'm getting errors thrown before I can even add the channel dynamically through JS.

Should I start with a default channel first?

Comment: Yes add a default channel